# Type mismatch from mappers while using MultipleInputs class

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have defined 2 mappers for processing 2 files seperately.

Ouput of first mapper-  
Output of second mapper-

In the driver code I am adding both mappers using addInputPath() of  MultipleInput class.

While running the jar I am getting **Type mismatch** of error.

```
16/04/24 18:40:28 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1461435780053_0008_m_000001_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in value from map: expected hadoop.StationObj, received org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.collect(MapTask.java:1077)
```

Below is the code

```
public static class customerMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable,Text,IntWritable,StationObj>
    {
        IntWritable outkey=new IntWritable();
        StationObj outvalue=new StationObj();

        //2,Russia,Jhonson,10000

        public void map(LongWritable key,Text values,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
        {
            String []cols=values.toString().split(",");
            outkey.set(Integer.parseInt(cols[0]));
            outvalue.setAmount(Integer.parseInt(cols[3]));
            outvalue.setCountry(cols[1]);
            outvalue.setProduct(cols[2]);

            context.write(outkey, outvalue);
        }
    }

    public static class countryMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable,Text,IntWritable,Text>
    {
        IntWritable outkey=new IntWritable();
        Text outvalue=new Text();
        public void map(LongWritable key,Text values,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
        {
            String []cols=values.toString().split(",");

            outkey.set(Integer.parseInt(cols[0]));
            outvalue.set(cols[1]);
            context.write(outkey,outvalue);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
        Configuration conf=new Configuration();
        Job job=new Job(conf,"dsddd");
        job.setJarByClass(stationRedJoin.class);
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);

        //job.setMaxMapAttempts(1);

        MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]), TextInputFormat.class, customerMapper.class);
        MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[1]), TextInputFormat.class, countryMapper.class);

        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[2]));

        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true)?1:0);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to pass all your **types** for both mapper and reducer (if any) in **Driver** class like :

```
//output format for mapper
       job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
       job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);  <---

//output format for reducer (if)
      job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
      job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

//use MultipleInputs and specify different Record class and Input formats
      MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, fPath, FirstInputFormat.class, MyFirstMap.class);
      MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, sPath, SecondInputFormat.class, MySecondMap.class);
```

Comment: I have 2 mappers. Below are the input and output types of both.

1st mapper-customerMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable,Text,IntWritable,StationObj>

2nd Mapper-countryMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable,Text,IntWritable,Text>

output types of both the mapper are different.